# How to convert a .txt to .dll

Tags: dll, compilation

So I got my hands on some C# code in .txt format and I want to convert it to .dll. I know that I can't just put ".dll" on the end of it. How can I get it converted into .dll format. I have searched for a long while on and havn't found anything useful. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: im new please no downvote

Comment: You need to create a new Class Library project in Visual Studio, then paste your code in and compile it.  Class Library projects save their files as a dll type.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to create a new class library project using Visual Studio, copy the class from txt file into a new cs file inside the project, then build the project and you will find your dll in bin/debug or bin/release folder

Comment: choosing between them is another topic, both work for you.